# How can I use a descriptor to implement a protocol?

Tags: python, interface, mypy, python-descriptors

Let's say I define a simple protocol using `typing.Protocol`, and a class that implements it:

```py
from typing import Protocol


class I(Protocol):
    def m(self, x: int) -> int:
        ...


class A(I):
    def m(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x + 1
```

So far, no problem, and `mypy` doesn't report any errors.  (I inherited explicitly from the protocol so that `mypy` would tell me if my implementation works or not.)

Now, let's say I want to implement my protocol with some classes that work similarly to how Python's built-in functions/bound methods work, that is accessing the attribute on the class gives an "unbound` instance, and accessing it on the instance gives me a "bound" instance that holds on to a reference to the instance, something like this:

```py
from typing import (
    Any,
    Callable,
    Generic,
    Optional,
    Type,
    TypeVar,
    Union,
    overload,
)

from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec


P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


class BoundField(Generic[P, R]):
    def __init__(
        self, func: Callable[Concatenate[Any, P], R], instance: Any
    ) -> None:
        self.func = func
        self.instance = instance

    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        return self.func(self.instance, *args, **kwargs)


class UnboundField(Generic[P, R]):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[Concatenate[Any, P], R]) -> None:
        self.func = func

    @overload
    def __get__(
        self, instance: None, owner: Optional[Type]
    ) -> "UnboundField[P, R]":
        ...

    @overload
    def __get__(
        self, instance: object, owner: Optional[Type]
    ) -> BoundField[P, R]:
        ...

    def __get__(
        self, instance: Optional[object], owner: Optional[Type] = None
    ) -> Union["UnboundField[P, R]", BoundField[P, R]]:
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return BoundField(func=self.func, instance=instance)

    def __call__(self, instance: Any, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        return self.func(instance, *args, **kwargs)


def decorator(func: Callable[Concatenate[Any, P], R]) -> UnboundField[P, R]:
    return UnboundField(func)


class B(I):
    @decorator
    def m(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x * 2


reveal_type(A.m)
reveal_type(A().m)
reveal_type(B.m)
reveal_type(B().m)
```

In this case, although the `B.m` object is not a function or a bound method, it implements all the behavior of a function or a bound method, so there's no reason `B` shouldn't be considered to implement the `I` protocol.  Unfortunately, `mypy` complains:

```bash
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.961 (compiled: yes)
$ mypy protodesc.py 
protodesc.py:77: error: Signature of "m" incompatible with supertype "I"
protodesc.py:81: note: Revealed type is "def (self: tmp.protodesc.A, x: builtins.int) -> builtins.int"
protodesc.py:82: note: Revealed type is "def (x: builtins.int) -> builtins.int"
protodesc.py:83: note: Revealed type is "tmp.protodesc.UnboundField[[x: builtins.int], builtins.int]"
protodesc.py:84: note: Revealed type is "tmp.protodesc.BoundField[[x: builtins.int], builtins.int]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Of course, I want to do more with my `UnboundField` and `BoundField` than just define the `__get__` and `__call__` methods, which is why I can't do something like `cast(Callable[Concatenate[Any, P], R], UnboundField(func))` inside the decorator (because I want to add other methods to `UnboundField` and `BoundField` and use them elsewhere, which mypy will complain about if it thinks that they are just simple `Callable`s without extra methods).

Note that mypy *does* understand descriptors in general, for example:

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, Optional, Type, TypeVar, Union, overload


T = TypeVar("T")


class B:
    def __init__(self, arg: int = 42):
        self.arg = arg


class D(Generic[T]):
    """Descriptor class."""

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, type: Type[T]) -> "D":
        ...

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: T, type: Optional[Type[T]]) -> B:
        ...

    def __get__(
        self, instance: Optional[T], type: Optional[Type[T]] = None
    ) -> Union[B, "D"]:
        return B() if instance is not None else self


class A:
    b: D = D()


reveal_type(A.b)
reveal_type(A().b)
reveal_type(A().b.arg)
print(A().b.arg)
```

```bash
$ mypy descriptor.py 
descriptor.py:33: note: Revealed type is "tmp.descriptor.D[Any]"
descriptor.py:34: note: Revealed type is "tmp.descriptor.B"
descriptor.py:35: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Is there some reason that I'm missing that this doesn't work, or is it a deficiency in `mypy`?

Comment: There are a lot of mechanisms of the language that are not "undestood" by static type checkers such as mypy. Some because it would be too complicated to implement, some because it would be plain impossible to implement with static type checking.
In this case, as you verified, the descriptor protocol is simply not implemented in mypy - although I think it would fit in the "implementable" category.

Comment: (on a side note: your `decorator` function is a no-operation - you could use the class `UnboundField` directly as a decorator with `@UnboundField`)

Comment: Actually, using `cast` inside the decorator is the only thing that occurs to me that could work for typing. Maybe you can get it to work with your other use cases?

Comment: `cast` doesn't work for me because I want to add other methods to my `BoundField` and `UnboundField` classes, and then use them elsewhere, but mypy complains because it thinks that those are just callables that don't have any other methods.

Comment: I realise the decorator doesn't do anything, but using a class directly as a decorator looks a bit off to me.

Comment: It's not the case that mypy doesn't understand decriptors.  I'll add an example to the question.